# What is the standard way to dispatch correctly emails sent from our different Jenkins jobs?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, mailing-list

Currently the recipients addresses of the emails that are sent at the end of a build are hardcoded directly in the groovy pipelines files. Obviously this is problematic when you have a hundred of different jobs and not everyone has access to our repository to add/remove their address.

We are currently trying to get GNU Mailman working, but for now we are having trouble setting it up with Office365 and our IT department is not giving us the permissions and tools we would need to set it up correctly.

So we are looking for an alternative like using text files on a network drive but we would like to avoid such an ugly solution. Is there a proper way or plugin to do this cleanly that I did not see?

Comment: you can use a cvs file to have you email addresses their and then use readfile plugin to read the csv file.

Comment: You could set up distribution lists and email to those rather than to individual email addresses.   This of course may also be a problem for your IT folks...